# xampp vhosts - unwanted redirect to https

Tags: https, xampp, localhost, vhosts

I use xampp on a windows machine.

This is my httpd-vhosts.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "F:/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "F:/xampp/htdocs/2018_xxx.de/public"
  ServerName xxx.dev
  <Directory "F:/xampp/htdocs/2018_xxx.de/public">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This is my C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   xxx.dev
```

On calling URLs like http://localhost/thisexists.php or http://localhost/thisonetoo.php , everything is fine!

The call http://xxx.dev however is redirected to https://xxx.dev and I get an abort page like this (firefox 59): **Insecure Connection - Your connection is not secure**

[error message insecure connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIuja.png)

With Chrome, Safari and Opera I get similar results. The only working browser is Edge - yikes!

**how can I avoid the redirection to https?**

Comment: You may wish to use a different example url - the ones you've used have a habit of leading somewhere NSFW...

Answer (score 3):

Found a simple answer to my question here: [Local virtual hosts show Privacy Error on Chrome due to HSTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47785872/local-virtual-hosts-show-privacy-error-on-chrome-due-to-hsts)

The simple solution: just stop using the .dev extension to something other like **.test**, for example my-new-blog.test

Comment: Works perfectly on Opera

Answer (score 0):

For anyone trying to use .net, like I was, change it to .com that it'll work.